# How to assign rows a number based on a level in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

data = {'City': ['NY', 'NY', 'Arizona'], 'Doctor': ['Dr. Prof. Vera', 'Dr. Prof. Vera', 'Dr. Martin'], 'Type': ['Checked', 'Checked', 'Ordered'], 'Covid-Patient': ['yes', 'no', 'no']}
df = DataFrame(data).set_index(['City', 'Doctor', 'Type'])
df['Dr-Nr.'] = pd.Series(df.groupby(['Doctor']).cumcount()+1)
```

Which results in:

[image]

But what I want is an individual number of the `Doctor` in a new column `Dr-Nr.`.
[image]

Apparently, the grouping by level `Doctor` does not seem to have an effect. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) here: `df['Dr-Nr'] = (pd.factorize(df.index.get_level_values('Doctor'))[0]+1)`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can `rank()` index level `Doctor`:

```py
df['Dr-Nr.'] =df.assign(d_=df.index.get_level_values('Doctor'))['d_'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

The order of indexing will be alphabetical here, so:

```py
                               Covid-Patient  Dr-Nr.
City    Doctor         Type
NY      Dr. Prof. Vera Checked           yes       2
                       Checked            no       2
Arizona Dr. Martin     Ordered            no       1
```